# How do I test my Proxmox VM Guest's Watchdog? (Windows 10 VM)

Tags: virtual-machines, qemu, watchdog

My Proxmox (Qemu) uses the i6300esb watchdog device driver. Windows shows the Watchdog Timer device under Device Manager.

How do I test this? I tried disabling the watchdog device but nothing happened after a few minutes, so that didn't work.

The ONLY relevant result I can find is a 20 year old topic on the Red Hat forums, stating that this driver is broken and should not be used:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=610063